# how to make image field in APEX Form?

Tags: image, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I am making DB in APEX for school in which they also require the field of students images to be displayed....I want to know how to make the image field in APEX form and to upload that image in that field.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[How to Upload and Download Files in an Application](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B31036_01/doc/appdev.22/b28839/up_dn_files.htm) which is part of [the 2-day developer guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B31036_01/doc/appdev.22/b28839/toc.htm) (something each starter should go through.)

Displaying images can be done through a page item of type "Display Image". A blob column can be defined there, and can be both a database column fetched through the created row fetch process, or a column retrieved through a sql statement. Take a look at the item and try around. This really is not too hard. For documentation, refer to [About BLOB Support in Forms and Reports (Oracle apex documentation)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23903_01/doc/doc.41/e21674/advnc_blob.htm)
There is plenty and plenty of information on this subject you can retrieve through google.

Take a look at page 6 of the Sample Database Application which is delivered in apex application and is built upon the DEMO_ tables. As a beginner this application showcases many techniques, and much can be learnt from it. On page 6 it shows how to deal with images, both uploading and displaying. If your local workspace has no such application, simply go to [apex.oracle.com](http://apex.oracle.com) and request a workspace. Each workspace contains the demo application. Invaluable when starting out.